# Why is my Reboot Policy not deploying or running

Tags: ps1

Could someone tell me why this script will not run on Microsoft Endpoint. This script is to reboot all computers on network on Tuesday at 2 pm every week with a warning 5 minutes before the reboot allowing the user to accept or decline the reboot.

```
# Set the reboot day and time
$rebootDay = "Tuesday"
$rebootTime = "14:00"  # 2:00 PM

# Calculate the time for the warning message
$warningTime = (Get-Date).Date.AddHours(13).AddMinutes(55)

# Create a script block for the task action
$actionScript = {
    # Check if it's the reboot day
    if ((Get-Date).DayOfWeek -eq $rebootDay) {
        # Calculate the current time
        $currentTime = Get-Date -Format "h:mm tt"

        # Check if the current time is after the warning time
        if ($currentTime -ge $warningTime.ToString("h:mm tt")) {
            # Show the warning message and get user response
            $result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Your computer will be rebooted in 5 minutes. Do you want to proceed with the reboot?", "Computer Restart", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning)

            if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Yes) {
                # Wait for 5 minutes before forcing the reboot
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 300

                # Perform the reboot
                Restart-Computer -Force
            } else {
                # User declined reboot
                [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Computer reboot declined. The system will not be rebooted.", "Reboot Declined", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
            }
        }
    }
}

# Define the trigger for the task (Weekly on the specified day and time)
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -At $rebootTime -DaysOfWeek $rebootDay

# Create the task action
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute PowerShell.exe -Argument "-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command $actionScript"

# Register the scheduled task
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "RebootTask" -Description "Scheduled reboot task with warning" -RunLevel Highest -Force
```